# Toolbar menu onOptionsItemSelected does not work from fragment

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-architecture-navigation

I'm trying to change current fragment when user clicks the menu in toolbar using navigation components, however I can't get the menu to work from fragment at all! I'm using bottom navigation bar with 2 fragments and each fragment has different toolbar menu items, I'm not using navigation drawer.
Here's a little snippet from HomeFragment.kt:

```
override​ ​fun​ ​onCreateView​(
    inflater​:​ ​LayoutInflater​, ​container​:​ ​ViewGroup?​,
    savedInstanceState​:​ ​Bundle?​
)​:​ ​View?​ {
    activity?.title ​=​ getString(​R​.string.title_home)
    setHasOptionsMenu(​true​)

    return​ inflater.inflate(​R​.layout.fragment_home, container, ​false​)
}

override​ ​fun​ ​onCreateOptionsMenu​(​menu​:​ ​Menu​, ​inflater​:​ ​MenuInflater​) {
    inflater.inflate(​R​.menu.toolbar_menu, menu)
    super​ .onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
}

override​ ​fun​ ​onOptionsItemSelected​(​item​:​ ​MenuItem​)​:​ ​Boolean​ {
    when​ (item.itemId) {
         R​.id.toolbar_about ​-​>​ {
            activity?.findNavController(​R​.id.bottom_nav_host)?.navigate(​R​.id.toAboutFragment)
             Toast​.makeText(context, ​"​You clicked on About menu​"​, ​Toast​.​LENGTH_SHORT​).show()
        }
        else​ ​-​>​ ​super​.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
    return​ ​true​
}
```

It doesn't even display the Toast that I specified. Could anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This could be related to your host Activity
- where do you set the supportActionBar to your toolbar?
- Which layout contains the toolbar the menu should be added to, your activity or fragment?

Comment: I set supportActionBar inside MainActivity (that's the only activity I got other than Splashscreenactivity and baseactivity which is for theme and language) onCreate method, layout that contains toolbar is activity_main.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this by calling `onOptionsItemSelected` directly from activity instead of fragment. So my final code looks like this:
`HomeFragment.kt`:

```
//We set menu from fragment
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) { 
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.toolbar_menu, menu)
    super .onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater) 
}
```

`MainActivity.kt`:

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean { 
    val navHost = findNavController(R.id.bottom_nav_host) 
    when (item.itemId) { 
        android.R.id.home -> { 
            onBackPressed() 
            return true 
        }
        //This one is for our fragment toolbar menu
        R.id.toolbar_about -> { 
            navHost.navigate(R.id.toAboutFragment) 
            return true 
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can open menu on your host Activity. If you wanna open it on Fragment, you can use context. Check the below code.

```
public class FragmentEditProfile extends Fragment {
    Context m_context;      //Context

    public static FragmentEditProfile newInstance() {
        return new FragmentEditProfile();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Get context of host activity.
        m_context = getContext();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View fragmentLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile_edit, container, false);

        // setNavigationOnClickListener of the host activity.
        ((MainActivity)m_context).toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Open the menu using context of host activity
                ((MainActivity) m_context).openDrawer();
            }
        });
        return fragmentLayout;
    }
}
```

If you have any questions, let me know. Hoping it will be helped.

Comment: Hi, I think I didn't specify some things, my bad. I don't have drawer, I only have one menu item that should replace current fragment using navigation components. I have set up menu items directly from fragment (I want to have different toolbar menus on different fragment) but for whatever reasons clicking that menu item does not work. I'm using bottom navigation bar btw

Comment: Fragment can't override functions of Activity. I suggest you use context of host activity.

Comment: ((MainActivity) m_context).onCreateOptionsMenu()  You can use like this.

Comment: Thanks I'll try that

Comment: If you have any problems, let me know. Hoping for your success!

Answer (score 0):

There are several things that might be checked

1)**Styles App Themes**

```
<resources>
<style name="AppThem
parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"> .....
```

2. **MainActivity** **FOCUS ON THIS**

- **setupBottomNavigationBar()**, and  **controller.observe(this, Observer { navController ->
  setupActionBarWithNavController(navController) })
  currentNavController = controller**

the fragment code does not work unless the main activity is set to support the action bar in the fragment. It took me a while to understand this....

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var currentNavController: LiveData<NavController>? = null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            setupBottomNavigationBar()}
    override fun onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState)
    setupBottomNavigationBar()
    }


    private fun setupBottomNavigationBar() {
        val bottomNavigationView = findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottom_nav)
        val navGraphIds = listOf(R.navigation.signin, R.navigation.register, R.navigation.elections_list)

        val controller = bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(
            navGraphIds = navGraphIds,
            fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager,
            containerId = R.id.nav_host_container,
            intent = intent
        )     
       controller.observe(this, Observer { navController ->
           setupActionBarWithNavController(navController) })
        currentNavController = controller
    }
    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        return currentNavController?.value?.navigateUp() ?: false
    }
  companion object
    }
```

3. in your menu/menu_collections. This is a working example only. much  this is referenced from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DMkzIOLppf4 and production by **Coding in Flow**

**Menu code**

```
<menu
     android:id="@+id/menu_collections_new"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/men_item1"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_icon"
        android:title="item1"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
        <item android:id="@+id/men_item2"
            app:showAsAction="never"
            android:title="item2"
            />
        <item android:id="@+id/men_item3"
            android:title="item3"
            app:showAsAction="never">
        <menu>
        <item
         android:id="@+id/subitem1"
        android:title="Subitem1"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/subitem2"
            android:title="Subitem2"/>
        </menu>
        </item>
        </menu>
```

4. **FRAGMENT CODE**
   set up the proper code in the actual fragment **FragmentOne.kt**
   **NOTE**
   **super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)**
   AND
   **inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_collections_new, menu)**

   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
   setHasOptionsMenu(true)
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
   }

   ```
   override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_collections_new, menu)
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {

        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.men_item1-> onSignOutClicked( "item1")
            R.id.men_item2 -> onSignOutClicked("item2")
            R.id.men_item3 ->onSignOutClicked("item3")
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)


        private fun onSignOutClicked(description:String) {
        Log.d(TAG,"dja 193 options menu selected $description")
        }
   ```